# my autocomplete not working in codeigniter + mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, autocomplete, codeigniter-3

I tried to populate data with autocomplete, but it seems did not work. I'm using JQuery Min V2.2.4, JQuery UI, and Codeigniter 3 with Bootstrap 3. When I tested the autocomplete with raw data, it did worked pretty good, but then I tried to populate the data from my table in MySQL, I keep wondering where is my fault.

this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#namapenerima').autocomplete({
                source : "<?php echo site_url('BackOffice/DataPPAT');?>",
                select : function(event, ui) {
                    $('[name="namapenerima"]').val(ui.item.labelnama);
                }
        });
</script>
```

I don't use $(document).ready(function() because when i tested with raw data, the autocomplete won't work.

Here's my View

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
     <label class="card-inside-title" for="namapenerima">Nama</label>
          <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-line">
                     <input type="text" name="namapenerima" id="namapenerima">
                </div>
           </div>
</div>
```

Here's my controller

```
public function DataPPAT()
    {
        $nm = $_GET['term'];
        
        if (isset($nm)) {
            $result = $this->BrowseAkun_m->DataPPAT_m($nm);
            if (count($result) > 0) {
                foreach ($result as $row)
                    $arr_result[] = array(
                        'labelnama' => $row->nama,
                    );
                echo json_encode($arr_result);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's my Model

```
function DataPPAT_m($nm)
    {
        $this->db->like('nama',$nm,'both');
        $this->db->order_by('nama', 'ASC');
        $this->db->limit(10);
        return $this->db->get('ppat')->result();
    }
```

I would appreciate anyone who helped me look for something I missed or something I put wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks ajax URL is not correct. Could you please try in this way instead of source using url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/User/userList" and make sure set base URL in the config file as like $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/demo';

Comment: what type of result you want?

Comment: @KUMAR I want the autocomplete shows data from my MySQL table

Comment: @MainulHasan i've changed the ajax URL several times, I also tried what you've suggested but still it won't worked :(

Comment: How do you get this data $_GET['term']; data? From your code, it's not clear. Did you debug? Is it return anything? Can you set any manual value and make sure your controller and model return data?